# Migrations with EF argumentexception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-migrations

When I try to put the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion in the DatabaseInitializer I always got this error :
"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index"

But, if I put another initializer it works normal, without changing the connection string.
Can someone helps me?

```
    <contexts>
      <context type="QIERPContext, QIERPDatabase">
        <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[QIERPContext, QIERPDatabase], [Migrations.Configuration, QIERPDatabase]], EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="Server=PC\\SQLSERVER;Database=qierp;User Id=sa;Password=******"/>
          </parameters>
        </databaseInitializer>
      </context>
    </contexts>
```

Comment: Is this `QIERPContext` the fully qualified name of the type? If the type lives in a namespace I think you need to use the full name.

Comment: Its like this: 
namespace QIERPDatabase
{
    public class QIERPContext : DbContext